# How to stop a sprite at exact touchdown position coordinates

Tags: libgdx

I want to move a sprite (which happens to be a Rectangle) from any position of the screen and make it stop at exactly the touched position of the screen. Now, I can stop my sprite already, but not at the exact touched position. I cannot find a good way of doing this without sacrificing either accuracy or risking the sprite to not stop at all.

Naturally - the problem arises because the current position is `Float`, so that Vector will never (or extremely rarely) have the exact same coordinates as the touch point (which is an `int`).

In the code below, I stop my sprite by simply checking the distance between the current position and the target position (i.e. the touched position Vector3), like so `if (touch.dst(currentPsition.x, currentPosition.y, 0) < 4)`.
For example, if the sprite is at position (5,5) and I touch the screen at (100,100), it will stop at like (98.5352,96.8283).

My question is, **how do I stop the sprite at exactly the touch position, without having to approximate?**

```
void updateMotion() {
    if (moveT) {
        movement.set(velocity).scl(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        this.setPosition(currentPosition.add(movement));
        if (touch.dst(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, 0) < 4)
            moveT = false;
    }
}

public void setMoveToTouchPosition(boolean moveT) {
    this.moveT = moveT;

    this.touch = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
    GameScreen.getCamera().unproject(touch);

    currentPosition = new Vector2(this.x, this.y);

    direction.set(new Vector2(touch.x, touch.y)).sub(currentPosition).nor();

    velocity = new Vector2(direction).scl(speed);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course sprite can't move smoothly to touch position and then stop in exactly the same position because of many reasons. Just change this

```
if (touch.dst(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, 0) < 4)
            moveT = false;
```

to this

```
if (touch.dst(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, 0) < 2) {
            currentPosition.x = touch.x;
            currentPosition.y = touch.y;
            moveT = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work very well. Ever so often the touch position will be missed when I check `if (touch.x == curpos.x && touch.y == curpos.y)`. Example scenario: Current Position is (96, 97) and touch is (100,100).
update()....
[cpx96, cpy96]
[cpx97, cpy96]
[cpx98, cpy97]
[cpx99, cpy98]
[cpx100, cpy99]
[cpx101, cpy100]
... and the touch point is missed.

As this was not enough - some times the touch point becomes a float as well (even though the Vector3 only takes `int`. I'm confused.

Comment: Setting the position is what was missing. It works just fine with `< 2`. If you add `this.setPosition(currentPosition);` and `moveT = false;` to the last if statement of your answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A quick yet acceptable solution to this could be the use of the `Rectangle` class. Considering you make a `Rectangle` surrounding the moving entity and constantly update it's bounds based on its current location, it's texture `width`, and it's texture `height`. You could stop it when it `overlaps` with the "target position". If you do this you guarantee yourself that it will stop exactly at that position. For example:

```
Texture entityTexture = new Texture("assets/image.png");

Rectangle entityBounds = new Rectangle();
entityBounds.set((currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, entityTexture .getWidth(), entityTexture .getHeight()));

Rectangle targetBounds = new Rectangle();
targetBounds.set((targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, 1, 1)); // make width and height 1 by 1 for max accuracy

public void update(){

  // update bounds based on new position

  entityBounds.set((currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y, entityTexture.getWidth(),   entityTexture.getHeight()));

  targetBounds.set((targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, 1, 1));

  if(entityBounds.overlaps(targetBounds)){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I did initially. It doesn't show in the code, but my entity is already a Rectangle. This solution is not at all accurate. Not only will the entity stop at random positions, even if you click/touch the same pixel multiple times, it will also occasinally miss the overlap and move away in some random direction..